# Not getting screenshot in mobile ios allure reports

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, appium, allure

I tried to get screenshot in my allure reports with Appium on IOS real device and I'm not getting it, what I did is :
in my mainRunner :

```
@Listeners({ utilities.AllureListeners.class })
```

in my Allurelisteners :

```
public class AllureListeners implements ITestListener  {

    IOSBaseTest iosBaseTest = new IOSBaseTest();
    
    public void onTestStart(ITestContext iTestContext) {
        System.out.println("I am on start method "+ iTestContext.getName());
        iTestContext.setAttribute("Driver", iosBaseTest.driver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println("I am on start method "+ getTestMethodName(result));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println("I am on testFailure method " + getTestMethodName(result)+" failed");
        //Object testClass = result.getInstance();
        //ITestContext context = result.getTestContext();
        //WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) context.getAttribute("driver");
        IOSDriver<MobileElement> driver = iosBaseTest.getdriver();
        if (driver instanceof WebDriver) {
            System.out.println("Screenshot captured for test case: "+getTestMethodName(result));
            saveFailureScreenShot(driver);
        }
        saveTextLog(getTestMethodName(result) + "failed and screenshot taken!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println("I am on test skipped method "+getTestMethodName(result)+" skipped");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedWithTimeout(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
    }

    private static String getTestMethodName(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        return iTestResult.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getName();
    }
    
    // Screenshot attachments for allure
    @Attachment (value ="page screenshot", type = "image/png")
    public byte[] saveFailureScreenShot(WebDriver driver) {
        return ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES); 
    }
    
    // Text attachments for allure
    @Attachment(value= "{0}", type = "text/plain")
    public static String saveTextLog(String message) {
        return message;
    }
    
    //HTML attachments for allure
    @Attachment(value= "{0}", type = "text/html")
    public static String attachHtml(String html) {
        return html;
    }
}
```

in my Base test I have method:

```
public IOSDriver<MobileElement> getdriver(){
    return driver;
}
```

my xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="utilities.AllureListeners" />
    </listeners>

    <test name="tester">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="add favorite contact" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.IOSMainRunner">
            </class>

        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

and yet my report looking without a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of the report]

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```java
public void allureSaveDeviceScreenshot() {
        Allure.addAttachment("screenshot", new ByteArrayInputStream(((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES)));
    }
```